# Moore-Penrose inverse and an underdetermined system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, pseudoinverse

I have the equation

$A\vec{x} = \vec{b} \tag{1}.$

where $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix of rank $m$, so that $m<n$ and the system is underdetermined. As I understand it, I can get the minimum L2 norm solution of the system by premultiplying $\vec{b}$ with the Moore-Penrose right inverse:

$\vec{x} = A^T(AA^T)^{-1}\vec{b}\tag{2}.$

What I don't understand is how I get from (1) to (2), i.e. what are the algebraic steps? I'm specifically interested in knowing how to do it with just basic matrix manipulations, without calculus.

Comment: If $A$ were invertible I would say: Left multiply on both sides by $A^{-1}$. Then left multiply on the right side by $I = A^T (A^T)^{-1}$ to get $x = A^T(A^T)^{-1}A^{-1} b$, which is equivalent to the right side you see there. but $A^{-1}$ and $(A^T)^{-1}$ are not sensible in this situation

Comment: There are lots of ways of deriving this.  Are you familiar with the singular value decomposition (SVD)?  Or the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions for constrained optimization problems?

Comment: I know how to solve the minimization problem with Lagrange multipliers if that's what the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions refer to, but I want to know how to get from equation (1) to equation (2) with just basic matrix manipulations, without calculus. Is it possible with the SVD?

Comment: Yes, it's certainly possible to do this using the SVD and the Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: Consider Eqn (2) to be an inspired guess (or ansatz) and observe that multiplying each side by $A$ recovers Eqn (1). This means that for this proposed solution $\|Ax-b\|_2\,$ is **identically** zero, which is the global minimum for any norm.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $x=u$ is a solution to the equation $Ax=b$. Let $u=u_0+u_1$ where $u_0\in\ker A$ and $u_1\in(\ker A)^\perp$. If $u_0\ne0$, then $Au_1=A(u_0+u_1)=b$ but $\|u_1\|<\sqrt{\|u_0\|^2+\|u_1\|^2}=\|u\|$, meaning that $u_1$ is also a solution to $Ax=b$ but with a smaller norm than $u$.

Therefore, if $x=u$ is a least-norm solution to $Ax=b$, its $u_0$ component must be zero. That is, $x$ must lie inside $(\ker A)^\perp$.

But what is $(\ker A)^\perp$? For any $x\in\ker A$, we have $\langle x,A^Ty\rangle=\langle Ax,y\rangle=0$ for all $y\in\mathbb R^m$. Therefore $\operatorname{range} A^T\subseteq(\ker A)^\perp$. As $\operatorname{rank}(A^T)=\operatorname{rank}(A)=n-\dim(\ker A)=\dim(\ker A)^\perp$, we conclude that $\operatorname{range} A^T=(\ker A)^\perp$.

Thus any least-norm solution $x$ to the equation $Ax=b$ must be in the form of $x=A^Ty$ for some $y$. Substitute the latter into the former, we obtain $AA^Ty=b$. Therefore, when $(AA^T)^{-1}$ exists, we have $y=(AA^T)^{-1}b$ and the least-norm solution is uniquely determined as $x=A^Ty=A^T(AA^T)^{-1}b$.

Answer (score 1):

We're looking for the Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse $A^+$ so that we have $\vec x = A^+ \vec b$.

Since $A$ is of full row rank $m$, we can have that $$AA^+=I \tag 3$$
Due to the full row rank we also have that $AA^T$ is invertible. So $$AA^T (AA^T)^{-1}=I \tag 4$$
If we compare equations (3) and (4), we can see that $$A^+=A^T (AA^T)^{-1}\tag 5$$ satisfies equation (3).

In theory there could still be a different matrix that is "better". However, the Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse is unique, and we can verify that the matrix in (5) satisfies the 4 conditions of the definition as given on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse).

Note that this approach only works if $A$ is of full row rank. Otherwise the formulas don't hold.

Answer (score -1):

$$|Ax-b|^2 = \left(Ax-b \right)^{T}\cdot\left(Ax-b \right)$$
$$ = \left(x^TA^T-b^T \right)\left(Ax-b \right)$$
$$ = x^T(A^TA)x - 2b^TAx +|b|^2$$ By differentiating the last line over $x$ and setting the
resulting gradient to 0 you get the required expression.

Comment: That's fine, but I'm specifically interested in how to solve it without calculus, if possible. I edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: This gives $x=(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$ when $A$ is a tall matrix of full column rank. Yet the $A$ in the OP is a fat matrix will full row rank and $A^TA$ is not necessarily invertible.

Answer (score -1):

A more geometrical interpretation is to project $b$ onto the column space of $A$. This projection is a linear combination of the columns of $A$, given by $Ax$. Then the "error" $b - Ax$ is orthogonal to the column space of $A$, so in particular to the columns of $A$. In other words, the dot product between each column of $A$ and $b - Ax$ is $0$, that is $A^T (b - Ax) = 0$. Therefore $A^T Ax = A^T b$.

I can recommend the online MIT class given by Gilbert Strang, it's absolutely brilliant to develop intuition.

Comment: How do you obtain $x=A^T(AA^T)^{-1}b$ from $A^TAx=A^Tb$?

Comment: Indeed. With my approach, you would get the left pseudo-inverse $(A^T A)^{-1} A^T$, not the right one.